# Jython 2.2 - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when accessing class .getPackage()

Tags: java, python, package, jython, jython-2.2

I have a Java class `myObj` with a static block as shown:

```
static{
    Class<myObj> klass = myObj.class;
    log.info("\nClientAPIVersion   : "+ klass.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());    
}
```

I'm creating an instance of this class in jython 2.2.

When I run my python script using :

`java -Dlog4j.configuration=file://${CLASSPATH}/log4j.xml -jar ~/jython_2.2/jython.jar test.py`

I get an exception as shown:

```
File "test.py", line 42, in ?
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I found online that `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` occurs due to a crash in the static block.

**When I remove the `log.info`, the python code executes correctly.**

I think that `klass.getPackage()` might be null, but if so, it should simply print 'null' in the log. Why the exception ?

What is the source of the problem and how may I fix it ? Thanks